# Fetch API - How to parse JSON file to HTML?

Tags: html, arrays, json, asynchronous, fetch-api

I'm trying to parse a JSON file to HTML with async Fetch API but I don't know how, please help me with few tips.

### quiz.json

```
    "quiz": {
        "q1": {
            "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
            "options": [
                "New York Bulls",
                "Los Angeles Kings",
                "Golden State Warriros",
                "Huston Rocket"
            ],
            "answer": "Huston Rocket"
        },
        "q2": {
            "question": "'Namaste' is a traditional greeting in which Asian language?",
            "options": [
                "Hindi",
                "Mandarin",
                "Nepalese",
                "Thai"
            ],
            "answer": "Hindi"
        },
        "q3": {
            "question": "The Spree river flows through which major European capital city?",
            "options": [
                "Berlin",
                "Paris",
                "Rome",
                "London"
            ],
            "answer": "Berlin"
        },
        "q4": {
            "question": "Which famous artist had both a 'Rose Period' and a 'Blue Period'?",
            "options": [
                "Pablo Picasso",
                "Vincent van Gogh",
                "Salvador Dalí",
                "Edgar Degas"
            ],
            "answer": "Pablo Picasso"
        }
    }
}
```

#### The wanted result

[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kdMF.png)

I did the result only with JSON.parse() and a for loop but it's not enough.
So far I tried this:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("get-text-btn");
        let textArea = document.getElementById("my-text-area");
        let loader = document.getElementById("loader");
        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            getData();
        });
        async function getData() {
            try {
                let response = await fetch('quiz.json')
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    throw new Error("Error while reading file.");
                }
                let json = await response.json()
                console.log(json)

                class Quiz {
                    constructor(question, options) {
                        this.question = question
                        this.options = options
                    }

                    getInfo() {
                        return "<h2>" + this.question + "</h2>" + "<br>" +
                            '<input type="radio">' + this.options + "<br>"
                    }
                }

                // This is where I got stuck

            } catch (error) {
                textArea.innerHTML = 'Fetch problem: ' + error.message;
            } finally {
                loader.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

```css
#loader {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            display: none;
        }

        #loader:after {
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            margin: 2px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 2px solid #241f1f;
            border-color: #241f1f transparent #241f1f transparent;
            animation: lds-dual-ring 1.2s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes lds-dual-ring {
            0% {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }

            100% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
        }

        #my-text-area {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: 16px;
        }
```

```html
<button id="get-text-btn">Get Data</button>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <textarea id="my-text-area" rows="30"></textarea>
```

A Quiz class must be created inside the script, which will have a constructor and a method that will allow displaying data. After processing the string read from the Fetch URL, it will have to be fragmented, Quiz objects will be created, and then, using the getInfo method, the data display will have to be performed for each object added in a string. I hope I've made myself clear.

Comment: Are you getting data here `console.log(json)`

Comment: That console.log is to check if the JSON is parsed correctly.

Comment: did you get data in console then?

Comment: Yes, JSON is parsed into an object.